# C++ Overload or monitor the dereference operator (on a pointer)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was wondering if it is possible to add code (checks of the validity of the object pointed to actually) when a pointer is dereferenced.
I saw many subjects on overloading operator ->, but it seems the operator was called on an object, not a pointer. Maybe (probably) there is something I'm misunderstanding.

here's an example :

```
T* pObj = new T();
pObj->DoStuff();    // call check code (not in DoStuff)
delete pObj;
pObj->DoOtherStuff();  // call check code (not in DoOtherStuff)
```

the "check code" should be independent from the function (or members) called. My idea was to set a member as an int in the class, and give it a defined value at construction (and destruction), then check the value.

As you may have guess I try to check for invalid pointers used. I try to read the code but it's far too big and complex to not miss many potential errors.

Thanks for your answers and insights.

Comment: If you're really worried about dangling pointers then use a smart pointer such as boost::shared_ptr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator->` can only be overloaded as a member function of a class, not for a normal pointer.

In general there is no way to check that a (non-null) pointer actually points to a valid object. In your example `delete pObj;` does nothing to change the pointer; it just leaves it pointing to invalid memory, and there is no way to test for that. So, even if you could overload `operator->` here, the best it could do is check that it wasn't null.

The usual approach is to use smart pointers, rather than normal pointers. A smart pointer is a class that wraps a plain pointer to an object, and has overloads of `operator*` and `operator->` so that it looks and feels like a pointer. You won't delete the object directly, but through the pointer (when it goes out of scope, or explicitly by calling a `reset()` function), and the pointer can then set its plain pointer to null when that happens. In that way, the plain pointer will always be either valid, or null, so the overloaded operators can usefully check it before dereferencing.

Smart pointers (and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) in general) bring other advantages too: automatic memory management, and exception safety. In your code, there will be a memory leak if `DoStuff()` throws an exception; `pObj` will go out of scope, and so there will be no way to access it to delete the object it points to. The memory will be lost and, if this keeps happening, you will eventually use all the system's memory and either crash or slow to a crawl. If it were a smart pointer, then the object would be deleted automatically as it went out of scope.

Commonly used smart pointers from the Standard Library and Boost are `auto_ptr`, `scoped_ptr` and `shared_ptr`, each with different behaviour when copying the pointer. C++0x will introduce `unique_ptr` to replace `auto_ptr`.

Comment: "he best it could do is check that it wasn't null". In practice, a check could do a little bit better than that with support from the type T. Add a "magicnumber" field to T, set it to a special value in the constructor, and set to some other value in the destructor (and make sure the compiler doesn't optimize away that assignment). Then if `pObj->magicnumber` has any other value, the object is certainly not live. Non-portable, of course, since reading free memory has undefined behavior, but in practice it's very unlikely to be any worse than calling the `DoOtherStuff` member function would be.

Comment: ... and btw can return false positives if the memory has been re-used for another object of the same type. But no false negatives.

Comment: Thanks for the answers ! This is what I feared. Anyway the additionnal information is great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should overload operators -> and *, in more or less the same way that auto_ptr works.
For example:

```
template<typename T>
class SafePtr {
public:
    SafePtr(T*p) : ptr(p) {}
    T &operator*()
    {
        if ( !preConditions() ) {
            throw runtime_error( "preconditions not met" );
        }

        return *ptr;
    }
    T * operator->()
    {
        if ( !preConditions() ) {
            throw runtime_error( "preconditions not met" );
        } 

        return ptr;
    }
    bool preConditions()
    { return ( ptr != NULL ); }

private:
    T* ptr;
};
```

This could be a very basic example. The -> operator would be overloaded in a similar way. All the logic you want to execute before dereferencing the pointer would be coded inside preConditions().  I think that you can get the idea from here, if not, you can ask further.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick already pointed out, use std::auto_ptr or better (and if possible) boost::shared_ptr. It basically implements almost exactly what you want.

To answer the question directly: indeed, you can only overload operator-> for a class, so in that case you won't be able to apply it to a pointer of that class. In other words, it will apply to objects, not pointers.

```
class T {
  T& operator->() { }
}; 

void f() {
  T* pObj = new T();
  pObj->DoStuff(); // Calls DoStuff, but... Oops! T::operator->() was not called! 
  (*pObj).DoStuff(); // Equivalent to the above
  delete pObj;
  (*pObj)->DoStuff(); // T::operator->() is called, but
      // there is no improvement here: the pointer is dereferenced 
      // earlier and since it was deleted, this will "crash" the application
  //pObj->->DoStuff(); // Syntactically incorrect, but semantically equivalent 
     //to the above
  pObj->operator->()->DoStuff(); // Semantically equivalent to the above two,
     //but avoids the double member access operator.
}
```

Comment: Is `->->` really syntactically incorrect? I think I've seen this before (it was actually a triple `->->->` if I recall correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem in my particular case is there are already a lot of code (hundreds of thousands of lines), so quite difficult (and probably risky) to change all the pointers.

Comment: @Giovanni Funchal, ahh, you've confused me. But it's good, because it made me think and try it out. And MSVC++ 2008 gave me a syntax error on `->->`. Calling `pObj->operator->()->DoStuff()` is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

`operator ->` (or any other operators) can be overloaded only for class objects and not for pointers. For your case, you can think of using standard/cutom **Smart Pointers** (which are actually objects and not pointer, but they can be used as of they are pointers).

If can not use smart pointers, then make a practice of assigning `NULL` after `delete/free`. Or you can use your custom wrapper for `delete` such as:

```
template<typename T>
void Destroy (T *&p)  // use this wrapper instead of 'delete'
{
  delete p;
  p = 0;
}
```

Comment: yes we set the pointers to null after deletion, but the problem is that there are a lot of pointers around the program pointing to the same objects (it's quite messy I agree, and somehow maybe we deserve what we've got ;)).